Authenticating a GitHub Action to Azure DevOps without User Personal Access Token
As part of a migration from Azure DevOps (ADO) to GitHub (GH) we are evaluating how to replicate a build Azure Pipeline (AzP) within GitHub Actions (GHA) which publishes a python wheel to an Azure Artifact Feed (AAF).
95% of the workflow is easily transferrable but there is one step which is not clear to me: authenticating the GHA runner to allow it to publish to AAF. The documentation states we should create a personal access token (PAT) which we should then add as a secret in the GH repository to then use as part of the GHA directly.
This workflow does not work for us, as there is not one user who should be providing access; rather, we want to provide authentication to the GHA pipelines themselves, like we do with our current AzP, which receive certain permissions by nature of being part of certain collections.
The only authentication we need to perform within our AzP is TwineAuthenticate. I realize it won't be 1:1, but I was wondering what the best practices are with authenticating GHA to ADO without needing to go through a user account, as we are a company with many hundreds of users and repositories.
This question doesn't only apply to AAF, it is a general GHA<->ADO integration question. For instance, this GHA to trigger an AzP also requires a PAT as part of its definition.

I found this document for your reference Use service principals & managed identities. It introduces

Add Microsoft Entra service principals and managed identities to your Azure DevOps organizations to grant access to your organization resources. For many teams, this feature can be a viable and preferred alternative to personal access tokens (PATs) when you authenticate applications that power automation workflows in your company.

In the Q&A Can I use a service principal to connect to feeds?, it shares the samples to connect to Azure Artifacts feed with a service principal. You can explore this to avoid use the personal access tokens in your GitHub Actions.
